# When exporting from LyX directly to .odt using tex4ht, the file is corrupted

Tags: lyx, export, libre-office

When trying to export any file from LyX to .odt, the file exports fine from LyX, i.e no errors noted. However, when I try to open in LibreOffice, the file is noted as being corrupted. Trying to repair the file fails, yet the file size is 2.4MB and I see that there is data when I open it in a text editor.

[image]

Comment: It might be worth to file a bug report to Lyx https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome

Comment: I do not imagine this is a LyX bug. LyX just calls tex4ht, so if there is a bug report, you could make a minimal example LaTeX file (by exporting from LyX) and make a bug report on tex4ht. Alternatively, you could consider using Pandoc for converstion to .odt.

Comment: @scottkosty I don't think I was aware of Pandoc, but there are so many utilities available it's hard to keep track. Thanks.